# What is a word for someone who is in pain but puts out a tough image?

Tags: single-word-requests

This person acts strong when really he is going through a hard time. What's an original word for this?

Comment: What do you mean by an "original" word?

Comment: He's a [stoic](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/stoic) *- a person who can endure pain or hardship without showing their feelings or complaining*

Comment: At least very closely related: [What do you call a person who keeps on going despite setbacks? (in one word, a noun)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/140158/what-do-you-call-a-person-who-keeps-on-going-despite-setbacks-in-one-word-a-n)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for:

> 1. **unflinching**: not showing fear or hesitation in the face of danger or difficulty.
> 2. **undaunted**: not intimidated or discouraged by difficulty, danger, or disappointment.
> 3. **steadfast**: resolutely or dutifully firm and unwavering.

Other words: unwavering, unshakable

Comment: I believe this person is scared, but he just doesn't show it. He puts up a disguise that makes others think he is brave and strong.

Comment: @miv399: It's a cheap reference to Game of Thrones, but somewhat valuable here: a man can only be brave if he is afraid. What you're trying to convey is that this man shows strength at a time where he feels weak (and would be expected to show that weakness). The three suggestions in this answer accurately describe that quality. All of them imply being brave/strong at a time where you'd be expected to show fear/weakness.